# NameError: name 'redis' is not defined - PySpark - Redis

Tags: python, apache-spark, redis, pyspark, redis-py

I am using the `addPyFile` method in pyspark to load the `redis.zip` file.
I am able to load the file using

```
sc.addPyFile("/home/path/to/redis.zip")
```

But while running the code using `./pyspark`, it is showing the error:

> NameError: name 'redis' is not defined

The zip(`redis.zip`) contains `.py` files(`client.py`, `connection.py`,`exceptions.py`, `lock.py`,`utils.py` and others).

Python version is - 3.5 and spark is 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pack py files into zip and add it using `sc.addPyFile` you should import modules using `import client`, `import connector`, etc.